# Knowing when your throat is open

Tags: voice

My vocal teacher notices quite often that I have a closed throat when singing. My problem is I don't have the physical awareness to know when my throat is open or closed. What are some techniques to help develop awareness of how open or closed my throat is.

Comment: Surely your teacher can explain that better than anyone? Maybe try out a few other teachers.

Comment: Back in my clarinet days, I had a little sign over my stand that read "egg in throat" .  Amazing how that helped me remember to keep my airway wide open.

Comment: @Dave My teacher did. I just want to get different opinions on how different singers approach opening the throat.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft's suggestion is what my teacher told me, too (calling it 'hot potato in throat'). You could also practice in front of a mirror, as a tense throat is quite easily spotted from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

One technique to relax the muscles in your throat (and open it up) is to keep your lips together and create a motorboat sound.  You do this three times, each time until you run out of breath.  It may sound silly but it does work.  I had vocal cord surgery a couple of years ago to supplement a paralyzed vocal cord.  When I had no voice I had developed a technique (unconsciously) that tightened up my throat so I could be heard -- but after the surgery I needed to stop doing this in order to not sound stressed.  I went to a speech therapist and that was one of the exercises that she gave me to open up my throat, and relax my vocal cords.

I don't know how to have physical awareness, although I've tried.  Using exercises like the one I mentioned should help open up your throat, if that's desired.